# Rails - Attribute change detection - undefined method `ip_address_changed?' doesn't work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, geolocation, rails-geocoder

In rails I have the code below in my User model.  It works fine when I run my development server, and doesn't throw any errors at all.  After pushing to Heroku I get the error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `ip_address_changed?' for #<User:0x007ff3da78d3d8>): app/controllers/users_controller.rb:55:in `update'
```

In my User model I have ip_address which could get updated.  According to the documentation and Railscasts by Ryan bates I can use the column name of :ip_address, and then add _changed? at the end.  So, I tried the line `:if => :ip_address_changed?`
How can I get this to work on Heroku, am I doing something that is not correct or is now deprecated?

```
  geocoded_by :ip_address
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude, :address => :location do |user, results|
    #further populate the model based on the :location
    if geo = results.first
      user.country = geo.country_code
      user.state = geo.state
      user.city = geo.city
    end
  end # end block reverse geocoded
  after_validation :geocode, :reverse_geocode, :if => :ip_address_changed?
```

I could just remove the `:if => :ip_address_changed?` but that would generate unneeded traffic to google api.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by another Ryan Bates video that covers tracked changes on attributes.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/109-tracking-attribute-changes

Reason is I was apparently bypassing the setter when doing the create! method or the `@user.update_attributes!(user_params)`.  This means it can't track changes unless I switch it to the normal `@user.save` without the bang `!`

I will do this soon, but for now the fix that Ryan Bates mentions in the video is to tell rails I'm changing an attribute on the model or that it will change since my logic requires it.

So in my controller, on my #update action I now have this.
Tested it on Heroku and it now works.

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])

    @user.ip_address = request.remote_ip
    @user.ip_address_will_change! #by passing setter method so the model will work

    # save data
    # this line also includes newly uploaded photos as well as profile info
    @user.update_attributes!(user_params)
    redirect_to users_path
  end
```